# How to organize a website that runs on Node-express server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm quite new to this. What I've got now is an `index.html` and `record.html`, a `application.js` file that contains All the logics and handles `XMLhttp` responses, and a `style.css` file.

Below is my node-express server. Currently it runs locally. It will need to be deployed to AWS later. My question is, what's the proper way to organize this project? Is this ok to just keep `html`, `js` and `css` in a `public` folder and keep the node server files together? I'm not coding any javascript in node server, is this an ok practice? Many thanks in advance!

Server:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.get('/record', function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public'+ '/record.html'));
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       fs.readFile('/index.html', function(error, content) {
          if (error) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          res.end();
       } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
}); 
  res.send('Hello World');   
});

https.createServer({
   key: privateKey,
   cert: certificate
}, app).listen(8080);

httpServer.listen(8443);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need an HTTP server.

All the static content should be served from the public folder, so you are doing it right. If your public folder contains an index.html file, it should open up when you visit http://localhost:8080

```
// Load required packages
var express = require('express');

// Create our Express application
var app = express();

// Add static middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Create our Express router
var router = express.Router();

// Initial dummy route for testing
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

});

// Register all our routes
app.use(router);

// Start the server
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks @xaxist. By saying 'All the static content should be...', you do not imply that this is a static website, right? Because my site does consume some APIs var xmlhttp request/response. I reckon I could say it's a dynamic website runs on a server, and that server is created by using node-express? Apologize if this is a stupid question..

Comment: A dynamic website implies that the content in the Html pages changes. If you can elaborate more on what exactly you are developing, I can help further.

Comment: Yes those html pages changes. I'm doing a demo website for using some APIs. It works ok now but I'd just like to confirm if I'm organizing those files properly n understand the concepts. I'm quite new n it's my first website project that runs on node-express.. So what's a node app? Does that refer to an app that keeps all the logics in that node server file?

Comment: I would suggest you go through a primer course in Node.js. A good free course can be found here - https://school.scotch.io/build-a-nodejs-website